# RegionIntersection of two Line-objects

Tags: regions

Looking for the intersection of two "boundary meshregions"

```
Show[{DiscretizeGraphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]],DiscretizeGraphics[Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 1}}]]}]
```

[image]

I tried

```
RegionIntersection[
DiscretizeGraphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]], 
DiscretizeGraphics[Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 1}}]]
]
```

without success. The  `RegionEmbeddingDimension` is equal `==2` but Mathematica (v11.01) doesn't evaluate.

What's wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 11.2 (11.3 & 12.0 also work, 11.1 doesn't evaluate as described in the question)

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, though I have to look for a workaround or an update...